# How to sort CSV file in python by time interval

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

I want to group a CSV file into clusters based on the time difference(difference of 30 minutes) between particular items from the CSV file.

Then I would like to use that sorted data for plotting so I need to sort the CSV file in a way in which I will be able to call x and y-axis on the chart with the new data.

So what I need is to sort this list by time and group it into sessions. One session is considered if the time difference is not bigger than 30 minutes. If it is bigger than 30 minutes it is considered a new session.

So user 2222 is only in 1 session
User 5555555 would be in 3 different sessions since item_id 0,2 and 1 were created at different days.

```py
=====================================
Sample dataset in CSV: 
=====================================

uuid,created_at,item_id
2222,2017-01-16 10:54:43.386,0
2222,2017-01-16 10:56:25.717,1
2222,2017-01-16 10:55:50.642,2
5555555,2017-01-16 10:54:19.796,3
5555555,2017-01-16 10:55:10.654,1
5555555,2017-01-17 10:54:55.643,2
5555555,2017-01-27 10:56:02.860,0
323232,2017-01-25 10:56:16.432,3

=====================================
                MY CODE
=====================================
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def sessions(filename):

    data = pd.read_csv(filename, parse_dates=[1])

    data_sort= data.sort_values(by=['uuid', 'created_at'])

    cluster = (data_sort["created_at"].diff() > pd.Timedelta(minutes=30))

    data_sort.groupby(cluster)
#print(data_sort.to_string())
    print()

    #print(cluster)

    #data_sort['c']=cluster

    #print(data_sort.to_string())

    a=data_sort.groupby(['uuid'])



    sessions=[]



    for name, group in data_sort.groupby('uuid'):

        session=group.groupby(group["created_at"].diff()>pd.Timedelta(minutes=30))

        for n,g in session:

            sl=g.values.tolist()

            sessiondict=dict()

            sessiondict['start']=sl[0][1]

            sessiondict['end']=sl[-1][1]

            sessiondict['uuid']=sl[0][0]

            sessiondict['count']=len(sl)

            sessions.append([sessiondict['uuid'],

                             sessiondict['start'],

                             sessiondict['end'],

                             sessiondict['count']])





    return pd.DataFrame(sessions)


========================================
              RESULT 
=======================================
0   1                2                                  3
0   2222    2016-12-25 11:27:22.905 2017-02-01 21:34:10.479 3
1   2222    2016-12-28 09:40:57.271 2017-02-01 21:29:22.404 1
2   5555555 2017-01-05 15:03:52.859 2017-01-16 19:04:01.355 4
3   5555555 2017-01-09 18:45:52.102 2017-01-16 18:30:06.578 2
4   323232 2016-12-12 20:49:47.972  2016-12-12 20:54:34.990 1
... ... ... ... ...
```

The problem I have is the following: the code does not take into account the first session. So in the case of user 5555555 I should have 3 total sessions. One on the 16, 2nd on the 17th and 3rd on the 27th.

Another problem is that I somehow change the name of the columns from uuid,created_at,item_id to 1, 2,3 as you can see in the Result.

So I would like to change the following code so that each session has it's own dates.

The expected result should be

```
uuid created_at session_id

5555555 2017-01-16 10:54:19 one session id
5555555,2017-01-16 10:55:10

5555555 2017-01-17 10:54:55 2nd session id

5555555 2017-01-25  3rd session id
```

So that then I can say how many sessions do 1 user have per day OR how long sessions last considering we have 2 or more items in one session.

Answer (score 0):

It's essential an island-and-gap problem. For each `uuid`, if the time gap between a row and its previous row is greater than 30 minutes. we start a new island.

Try this:

```
def summarize(group):
    return group.assign(
        session_id=group['created_at'].diff().div(pd.Timedelta(minutes=1)).gt(30).cumsum()
    )

df.sort_values(['uuid', 'created_at']) \
    .groupby('uuid').apply(summarize) \
    .reset_index(drop=True)
```

Result:

```
      uuid              created_at  item_id  session_id
0     2222 2017-01-16 10:54:43.386        0           0
1     2222 2017-01-16 10:55:50.642        2           0
2     2222 2017-01-16 10:56:25.717        1           0
3   323232 2017-01-25 10:56:16.432        3           0
4  5555555 2017-01-16 10:54:19.796        3           0
5  5555555 2017-01-16 10:55:10.654        1           0
6  5555555 2017-01-17 10:54:55.643        2           1
7  5555555 2017-01-27 10:56:02.860        0           2
```

---

Here's how it works:

- `diff()` calculate the difference between the current row and previous, the result is a `Timedelta` object
- `div(...)` convert the `Timedelta` object into decimal minute (i.e. 10.6 minutes)
- `gt(30)` checks if the time gap is greater than 30 minutes. If yes, it returns `True <=> 1`, which starts a new island.
- `cumsum()` get the cumulative sum, which has the effect of assigning each row to the corresponding island.